# ASP.net render HTML nicely (Beautify)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

When I generate my controls in ASP.net they come out like this:

```
<div id="ctl00_mainContent_ApprovalSelectPanel" class="discussWrapper">

        <span class="cbox highlighted"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl00" checked="checked" value="70" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00">Buyer1</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl01" value="75" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl01">Buyer2</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl02" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl02" value="280" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl02">Client3</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl03" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl03" value="281" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl03">Client4</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl04" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl04" value="283" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl04">Client2</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl05" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl05" value="289" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl05">Client1</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl06" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl06" value="346" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl06">artworker1</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl07" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl07" value="362" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl07">buyer3</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl08" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl08" value="367" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl08">meeeee</label></span><span class="cbox"><input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl09" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl09" value="368" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_ctl09">stake</label></span>

    </div>
```

Pretty ugly and hard to understand when you view the source.  This isn't a problem usually, but my site is offering visitors resources and tutorials where *looking at the source* is part of the experience.

Is there any way to render these controls nicely?  Indented properly,  better id's and names etc?

Comment: You're not going to get pretty source code with webforms.  If you want to use ASP.NET MVC is a much better proposition.

Comment: I personally find that the names (as long and "ugly" as they appear) are a very sensible way, especially with scenarios involving repeaters, nested controls, templates, and pretty much "everything non-trivial"; just use better CSS classes/selectors (avoid ID-based selectors for ASP.NET controls) and data-binding (to avoid hard-coding the Client ID) and *do not* treat the generated names as a static resource.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 you can set the ClientIDMode to one of 4 options AutoID, Static, Predictable and Inherit. You're probably looking for Static as this will ensure that your controls render to the page with the IDs you've assigned to them.

You can set it at application level by adding:

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static">
```

To your web.config

There's more details on these changes here: http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx

Comment: This looks great for ID's thanks, any ideas on indenting and line breaks?

Comment: This is awesome. Does this apply to name as well as id or just id? This will make scripting and css far easier than before. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Man, wish I had that when I was coding ASP.NET 2.0 apps.

Comment: This is only a tiny, tiny part of "beautification". I prefer to have the "long control names" as it avoids name clashes. Always; this becomes much bigger issue with complex pages and [many] nested controls. It also allows some [unsanctioned] heuristics to be performed upon the control names.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.NET WebForms HTML rendering and control markup have been improved in .NET 4.0 and this will help with the control IDs and structure of the HTML elements themselves (as mentioned in [Rob Stone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258921/asp-net-render-html-nicely-beautify/5259018#5259018) to your question).  However, the indents and line breaks might still be less than desirable for your needs.

If the HTML source *truly* is part of the user experience for your application, you might **consider writing an HttpModule** attached to the [ReleaseRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.releaserequeststate.aspx) event.  This approach will address the actual line breaks and indentations of your HTML source.  To **[avoid re-inventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy)** you could use either the [.NET port of HTML Tidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) or a [.NET Wrapper for HTML Tidy](http://tidyfornet.sourceforge.net/) as part of your custom filter on the response.

There is a nice example of how you might write a custom filter in an HttpModule in [this blog](http://www.orthogonal.com.au/computers/blog/0170.htm).  The section of the code that I found most useful is as follows (slightly edited but you can get the full understanding from the blog itself):

```
public class CustomModule : IHttpModule
{
  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
    context.ReleaseRequestState += new EventHandler(context_ReleaseRequestState);
  }

  private void context_ReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    if (string.Compare(response.ContentType,"text/html",true) == 0)
    {
      response.Filter = new CustomFilter(response.Filter,response.ContentEncoding);
    }
  }
}
```

and inside your CustomFilter class...

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
  sb = new StringBuilder(count + 1024);
  sb.Append(enc.GetString(buffer,offset,count));

  // <---- Run the sb content through HTML Tidy here ---->

  byte[] buff = enc.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
  s.Write(buff,0,buff.Length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting proposition; however, if nobody but a developer cares about how the source looks, so long as the HTML is valid (for the browser) .. then it's just wasted resources .. so this approach might be best to only do in "development" modes.

Comment: @pst - I agree with your comment for the majority of web sites.  In this case though the OP has stated _"my site is offering visitors resources and tutorials where looking at the source is part of the experience."_ so it is probably worth the extra resources from that viewpoint.  Makes sense right?

Comment: So why *lie* about the ASP.NET experience? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Getting pretty *output* is going to be a near impossibility, because the parser does not have any concept of context when rendering controls. Many controls render more than one HTML element, and they would need to know their context to do this... as well as be able to know what kind of formatting was desired (e.g. for list controls, when to start a new line, when to indent again).

Also, not all elements in markup are actually rendered, and the layout of your markup is not always directly related to the layout of the output. For example:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel />
</asp:PlaceHolder />
```

`Placeholder` is not rendered, so would that cause an indent in the output or not? `DropDownList` renders multiple HTML controls, and there's no way for it to determine the desired way of being rendered: should it indent to the same level as the first control? Should it render with no inter-element spacing? From a practical standpoint, it's more efficient to render with no spacing at all (which is what most controls do) to minimize the amount of data that needs to be sent to the client.

Finally, even in the simple cases, the actual representation when you "view source" from a browser will probably be different between browsers. They can all choose to handle spacing, line breaks, indentation in any way they choose, since inter-element spacing does not affect rendering in any way.

If you are showing "before/after" examples on your web site you really don't have much choice except to manually format the output for presentation, if this is what you want. If people want to look at the source too, that's fine, but it would be very challenging to make the source consistently look as good as your markup.

If this was really important to you, you could intercept the output stream and reformat it before sending to the client, but it won't happen directly from asp.net's rendering engine. For an example of how to do this, google "asp.net response filter" - [here's one.](http://aspnetlibrary.com/articledetails.aspx?article=Use-Response.Filter-to-intercept-your-HTML) I'm sure it's not hard to find code that formats HTML that you could apply to this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here, but I faced a similar problem. We were generating some highly complex javascript that was getting way too mangled to reasonably debug with it all jumbled in line with the rest of the markup. So I came up with this class.

```
public class HtmlPrettyControl : HtmlGenericControl
{
    public bool Indent { get; set; }

    public HtmlPrettyControl(string tag) : this(tag, true) { }

    public HtmlPrettyControl(string tag, bool indent) : base(tag)
    {
        Indent = indent;
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Here you can check if you are running against a production environment
        // and just do base.Render to prevent extra code execution and space in
        // your response to the client

        if (Indent)
        {
            RenderBeginTag(writer);
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.Indent++;
            base.RenderChildren(writer);
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.Indent--;
            RenderEndTag(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Render(writer);
        }
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var myDiv = new HtmlPrettyControl("div");
var myLabel = new HtmlPrettyControl("label", false);
myLabel.InnerText = "I'm sorry, Dave.";
myDiv.Controls.Add(myLabel)
```

Generates markup:

```
<div>
    <label>I'm sorry, Dave.</label>
<div>
```

We use a similar Render method override for the controls that aren't simple Html tags (in a different base class/inheritance chain). The only downside is that the `writer` passed to the `Render` method does not seem to be informed of the current indentation level of an ascx that your control is living on (if any). So while the hierarchy of the control and its children is nicely indented and broken up, they will reset to an indentation level of 0, breaking the overall flow from surround markup on your ascx or aspx layout files.

Comment: I would argue the fundamental problem here, is shoving in JavaScript with the plain markup ;-) I have a control (actually two, depending on context) just to facilitate with JavaScript rendering for inclusion of markup and code-behind that also takes care of the other details; inline events are also decoupled in a similar fashion with "binding" to managed JavaScript function stores.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I would never argue that our current approach (the problem I was trying to solve with this class) was ideal or even elegant. But this particular solution here, I think, is on point for the original question.