# How to prevent reformat of asp.net generated html

Tags: html, asp.net, code-formatting

When you have e.g. a `<head>` tag as `runat="server"` in **asp.net** and run the project and in the browser go view-source, the line breaks differ and the code is no longer formatted cleanly. This is even more apparent when dynamicly adding/removing controls.

The result is the source then looks less professional and messy to nosy clients. I heard that for SEO purposes cleanly formatted code is also better.

Could it be possible to prevent **asp.net** from ruining the formatting ?

**EDIT**
I found mention of writing a HttpModule that builds on the .net port of Tiny HTML (here [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258921/asp-net-render-html-nicely-beautify)). Could it be that someone has already written such a module that can be re-used ?

Comment: Suggest a read of this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258921/asp-net-render-html-nicely-beautify

Comment: Thanx Chris, this does give some insight I was hoping for a simple solution and not some custom development that might take days =/